# How to reduce duplicate queries in Django?

Tags: django, django-queryset

My problem is in optimization Django queries.
I'm working on school project: web-app when you can get some tasks.
I wrote code for generate variants with tasks, each variant have 25 tasks.
The problem is that django sent 54 queries, i can understood 4 of them, and 25 of them, but somehow django sent 25 queries additionally.
Here are duplicate query sets(i need only second):

```
4:{'sql': 'SELECT "SolveGiaApp_task"."id", "SolveGiaApp_task"."type_number", "SolveGiaApp_task"."text", "SolveGiaApp_task"."answer", "SolveGiaApp_task"."photos", "SolveGiaApp_task"."files", "SolveGiaApp_task"."rating", "SolveGiaApp_
task"."category_id" FROM "SolveGiaApp_task" WHERE ("SolveGiaApp_task"."rating" <= 5 AND "SolveGiaApp_task"."type_number" = 1) ORDER BY "SolveGiaApp_task"."rating" DESC LIMIT 1', 'time': '1.859'}

5:{'sql': 'SELECT "SolveGiaApp_task"."id", "SolveGiaApp_task"."type_number", "SolveGiaApp_task"."text", "SolveGiaApp_task"."answer", "SolveGiaApp_task"."photos", "SolveGiaApp_task"."files", "SolveGiaApp_task"."rating", "SolveGiaApp_
task"."category_id" FROM "SolveGiaApp_task" WHERE ("SolveGiaApp_task"."rating" <= 5 AND "SolveGiaApp_task"."type_number" = 1) ORDER BY "SolveGiaApp_task"."rating" DESC', 'time': '0.047'}
```

I expecting reduce amount of queries from 50(tasks) to 25, because django sent 2 queries(one with 'LIMIT 1') and same query , but without 'LIMIT 1.

Here is the function:

```
def get_task_closets_to_difficulty(type_number, difficulty):
    tasks_of_type_number_ordered = Task.objects.filter(type_number=type_number, rating__lte=difficulty).order_by(
        '-rating')
    max_rating = tasks_of_type_number_ordered[0].rating
    tasks = []
    for task in tasks_of_type_number_ordered:
        if task.rating == max_rating:
            tasks.append(task)
    return random.choice(tasks)
```

Comment: It usually depends on how you write your queryset function, and its context. Post your view function (or anywhere you put the queryset).

Comment: `I wrote code for` _show the code_.

Comment: Ok, i will upload piece of code, now

Comment: Maybe its because of calling .rating in 3d string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see, it appears called `.first()` on a queryset, then iterating over all elements.
Iterating over your queryset whill fill a cache that will be used on subsequent slices.

```
qs = MyModel.objects.all()
for instance in qs:
   ...

first = qs[0]  # No sql query will occur
```

On the contrary, `.first()` will always ignore cache

```
qs = MyModel.objects.all()
for instance in qs:
   ...

first = qs.first()  # This will result in a DB hit
first = qs.first()  # This too
```

In your case, you could eliminate the LIMIT1 query by casting to a list that forces the entire resultset to be resolved and then taking a slice

```
def get_task_closets_to_difficulty(type_number, difficulty):
    tasks_of_type_number_ordered = list(Task.objects.filter(type_number=type_number, rating__lte=difficulty).order_by(
        '-rating'))
    max_rating = tasks_of_type_number_ordered[0].rating
    tasks = []
    for task in tasks_of_type_number_ordered:
        if task.rating == max_rating:
            tasks.append(task)
    return random.choice(tasks)
```

Comment: I didn't use .first()

Comment: You took a slice before the cache was filled so thats equivalent.

Comment: You could just iterate over the tasks and breaking as soon as you see a different rating. This would get rid of your limit 1 query

Comment: sorry, but honestly, i didnt understand where i can do that

Comment: An even simpler solution would be to cast to a list so you'll be taking a slice of a list instead of a queryset. I updated my answer